# Google Drive Android: Error signing in the specified account. Please choose a different account

Tags: authentication, google-drive-api

I am implementing the google drive use google play services. 
I enable drive Api and Drive SDK from api console, and implemented configuration settings for Drive SDK, But when I try to login from my application, I get the following error,
Error signing in the specified account. Please choose a different account,
I add another account but facing the same error,
I did not know what is the problem? did I have to add the test users? but I did not find any place to test users.
In authentication section (https://developers.google.com/drive/web/enable-sdk#drive_integration). I found . In order to authenticate Drive users with the user info service, you must manually enter the following two scopes:

email
 profile

But scope section only allow to enter the url and not the email and profile.

Comment: Is there anything in your logcat to show? You also linked the web api. For Android, you should be looking at [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth)

Answer (score 1):

In the Google Developers Console, the package name must be the same as the Android app's package name in your android studio.
If you enter the wrong name, you may get this error message.

Comment: Also make sure `AndroidManifest.xml` correctly links the app to the project: https://developers.google.com/drive/android/java-client#set_mime_types_in_the_app_manifest.

Comment: Also make sure that the applicationId in the build.gradle file also matches the package name defined in the Google Developer Console and the AndoridManifest.xml